# Conics property proof

Tags: conic-sections

Prove this general Conics property of focal rays product as shown ( $a$ major axis, $b$ minor axis and focal ray makes angle $\psi$ with tangent) :

$$ r_1 \cdot r_2 = r (2 a -r) = b^2/\sin^2\psi $$

[image: ConicsProperty]

Comment: Your ideas?????

Comment: What are $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r$?

Comment: It looks like $r$ and $2a-r$ are the segments joining the foci to a point on the ellipse, but these aren't *chords* (focal or otherwise). Also, $r_1$ and $r_2$ don't seem to be defined (unless they're $r$ and $2a-r$). Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Yes, $ r_1=r,  r_2= 2a - r $ are from foci as you guessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we apply the Law of Cosines to your triangle, we find
\begin{align*}
(2c)^2 &= r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2r_1r_2 \cos(\pi - 2 \psi) \\
4c^2 &= r_1^2 +r_2^2 +2 r_1 r_2  \cos 2\psi \\
4c^2 &= r_1^2 + r_2 ^2 +2r_1r_2(1-2 \sin ^2 \psi) \\
4c^2 &= (r_1+r_2)^2 - 4 r_1r_2 \sin^2 \psi \\
4c^2 & = (2a)^2 - 4 r_1 r_2 \sin^2 \psi  \\
4r_1 r_2 \sin^2 \psi &= 4a^2 -4c^2 = 4b^2 \\ 
r_1 r_2 &= \frac{b^2}{\sin^2 \psi}
\end{align*}

Edit:  If you wished to handle the ellipse and hyperbola simultaneously it would perhaps be best to call the angle in the triangle opposite the major axis $\theta$, so that for the ellipse $\theta = \pi-2\psi$ and for the hyperbola $\theta = 2\psi$.
\begin{align*}
(2c)^2 &= r_1^2 + r_2^2 - 2r_1r_2 \cos \theta \\
4c^2 &= r_1^2 +r_2^2 \pm 2 r_1 r_2  \cos 2\psi \quad \text{(taking + for the ellipse and - for the hyperbola)}\\
4c^2 &= r_1^2 + r_2 ^2 \pm 2r_1r_2(1-2 \sin ^2 \psi) \\
4c^2 &= (r_1\pm r_2)^2 \mp 4 r_1r_2 \sin^2 \psi \\
4c^2 & = (2a)^2 \mp 4 r_1 r_2 \sin^2 \psi  \\
\pm4r_1 r_2 \sin^2 \psi &= 4a^2 -4c^2 = \pm 4b^2 \\ 
r_1 r_2 &= \frac{b^2}{\sin^2 \psi}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hope you include sign change to include the hyperbola here as well.

Comment: I see no change of angle needed in either case, also as per this re-labeled sketch including reflected rays optical picture.

Comment: @Narasimham  The tangent line to the hyperbola bisects the angle formed by the lines through the foci

Comment: All right, so the labels for hyperbola should be maked in compliment value.